# Mysql not between time and dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
user | completed
mike | 2016-07-10 19:00:00
john | 2016-07-11 08:00:00
```

I am trying to select all rows in a database where the row completed is NOT between 14:00 the previous day and the current day before 10:00. The script is designed to be run at 10:30 everyday

I've tried this

```
SELECT name FROM daily_tracking WHERE completed NOT BETWEEN now() - interval 1 day AND NOW() - INTERVAL 8 hour
```

Comment: You should consider giving us the errors/the problem you get when performing your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write it this way, which I prefer...

```
SELECT dt.name
  FROM daily_tracking dt
 WHERE dt.completed BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 HOUR AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use  date_sub

```
SELECT name 
FROM daily_tracking 
WHERE completed NOT BETWEEN date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 day ) 
   AND date_sub(NOW(),  INTERVAL 8 hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not depend on the exact time when the script is being run.  Instead, use arithmetic based on the current date:

```
SELECT dt.name
FROM daily_tracking dt
WHERE completed < date_sub(curdate(), interval (24 - 14) hour) or
      completed > date_add(curdate(), interval 10 hour);
```

This will work on a given day, regardless of the time the script is run.